# can't load index.html using webhostingforstudents cpanel with godaddy domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, hosting

I have purchased `Godaddy.com` domain , and purchased one year student hosting using

```
webhostingforstudents.com
```

But what i am trying to do is testing the web-hosting using basic index.html
but *"This website is temporarily unavailable, please try again later. "*
or redirect my website to :
[image]
I have figured out that are some settings of domain name system or Redirection need to be configured properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change your Domain's Name Servers to your Hosting provider's (webhostingforstudents.com). See this link to change Name Servers in Godaddy panel https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-us-12317 . 
           If you don't know your Hosting providers Name Servers, contact them, they will give you Name Servers to change. It may take 2-4 hours to effect Name Servers change. After that you can manage your site from your Hosting Panel.